# Есть ли опасность в Callback API Вконтакта?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, безопасность, callback

Просто есть план заказать мобильное приложение для одной группы вконтакта, 
и оно должно коннектится к Callback API,
и дать заказ фрилансеру -

нет ли опасности, что фрилансер что-нибудь такого накодит, от чего будет вред?

И вообще, используя API Вконтакта, можно ли навредить паблику?

Comment: А сделать для тестирования специальную ненужную группу не вариант?

Comment: Спасибо. Подумаю над этим.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мобильное приложение, вероятно, подразумевает и какую-то серверную часть – ведь именно сервер будет подключен к [Callback API](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api) и станет получать от ВК уведомления о событиях в группе. Если сервер не под вашим контролем, а фрилансера, то вы не контролируете, кто имеет доступ к данным. Возможна утечка данных о событиях в группе.

В частности, конкурентам может быть интересна ваша **свежая аудитория** – те, кто только что вступил в вашу группу, а значит, живой аккаунт, проявляющий интерес к вашей тематике. «Угон» свежих вступивших – довольно распространённая механика. Многими средствами можно находить тех, кто недавно вступил в любой паблик. Далее им пишут ЛС с предложением со скидкой купить то же, или вступить в другой паблик, или поливают негативом исходную группу и их бизнес.

Callback API – самый быстрый способ перехватить свежего вступившего, ведь событие передаётся на сервер мгновенно, как только человек вступает в группу. Но т.к. этот API доступен только владельцам группы, конкурентам обычно сложно до него добраться. В случае с непонятным фрилансером и его сервером эта задача облегачается (теоретически).

Вероятно, одним чтением данных приложение не ограничится. Будут задействованы и другие методы API – отправка сообщений пользователям, модерация комментариев. В этой области тоже могут быть косяки – если, например, всем обратившимся с сообщением в сообщество будет уходить ответ с дурным содержанием )

Наконец, худший возможный косяк, что приложение удалит всех подписчиков, запостит нелегальный контент, что приведёт к постоянной блокировке сообщества. Теоретически такое тоже возможно.

Это всё теории. По-моему самая реальная угроза, как и написал Pavel Mayorov, – это фрилансер, получивший деньги, и исчезнувший, так ничего толком и не сделав.

Comment: "худший возможный косяк, что приложение удалит всех подписчиков, запостит нелегальный контент, что приведёт к постоянной блокировке сообщества. Теоретически такое тоже возможно".
*********************************
Да, но для этого нужен доступ к API? Через Callback API это же невозможно?

Comment: через методы Callback API такое невозможно. [Удалять юзеров](https://vk.com/dev/groups.removeUser) может только Standalone приложение: «настоящее» мобильное или десктопное, или их имитация в браузере, где для авторизации попросят вручную скопировать адресную строку и вставить в форму – не делайте этого!

Answer (score 4):

Прямая угроза от Callback API отсутствует, поскольку доступ там только на чтение. Возможна утечка данных - но у вас и так паблик.

Если же говорить о API Вконтакта в целом - то, разумеется, навредить можно сотней разных способов, ведь через API можно делать почти все то же самое, что можно делать через веб-интерфейс.

PS не забывайте о главной угрозе, исходящей от фрилансеров - они могут накодить неработающее приложение.